# How to run a Video Presentation on Android in loop?

Tags: android, video, boot, presentation

I have a group of Android Tablets and I need them to only run a Video Presentation as Company Gift Card.

The idea of this project is the same of usually Company's Gift PENs, where the Company give to their presentation audience the information in the PEN, but this case we will have on an Android Tablet.

So this reason I'll need to have a startup Application on boot time and block the event until a root or a system reset. Off course I am aware of this last question and it's not a problem to the company.

Please give me some idea about how to solve this problem, in first time I need to make the video start and launch at boot time and then make it a loop or just lock in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by setting my app to run as the launcher. You can do this by putting this intent filter on your main activity:

```
<activity ...>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

The first time you run your app, press the home key and select the option to make your app the default launcher app. Then you can hand off the tablets for the event. Users will not be able to easily leave your app, since pressing home will return them to it. You should also prevent the back key and run fullscreen to hide other ways of navigating out of the app.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me a good option. I'll try and invest some of my time investigating the better point for the project with other options.